# should I give type?

Tags: dart

Should I give type when creating variable?

Any downside for just declaring the keyword "var"?

Any difference between these two?

`var a ＝ 0;
 int a ＝ 0;`

Comment: no, you can use both

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Pros/Cons

`ONGOING WORK`

## Best Practices

It's recommended to use `var` or [`final`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_final_locals.html) keyword, without specifying type annotation, and implicitly infer type for **known local variables**. Otherwise it's recommended to specify type annotations. As for `dynamic` keyword, it should be used very sparingly in specific use-cases, when you're doing manual type checking. For example `print(myVariable is SomeType)`.

[`omit_local_variable_types`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/omit_local_variable_types.html) Dart linter rule encourages omitting type annotation for **known local variables**. [`always_specify_types`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/always_specify_types.html) encourages specifying type annotations for cases that don't fall into the scope of the former linter rule.

### 1. [Style guide for Flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo)

#### 1.1 [avoid using `var`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo#avoid-using-var)

> All variables and arguments are typed; avoid "dynamic" or "Object" in
>   any case where you could figure out the actual type. Always specialize
>   generic types where possible. Explicitly type all list and map
>   literals.
>
> This achieves two purposes: it verifies that the type that the
>   compiler would infer matches the type you expect, and it makes the
>   code self-documenting in the case where the type is not obvious (e.g.
>   when calling anything other than a constructor).
>
> Always avoid "var". Use "dynamic" if you are being explicit that the
>   type is unknown, but prefer "Object" and casting, as using dynamic
>   disables all static checking.

### 2. [Dart Lint Rules](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/)

#### 2.1 [`omit_local_variable_types`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/omit_local_variable_types.html)

> **CONSIDER** omitting type annotations for local variables.
>
> Usually, the types of local variables can be easily inferred, so it
>   isn't necessary to annotate them.

#### 2.2 [`always_specify_types`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/always_specify_types.html)

> **DO** specify type annotations.
>
> Avoid `var` when specifying that a type is unknown and short-hands that
>   elide type annotations. Use `dynamic` if you are being explicit that the
>   type is unknown. Use `Object` if you are being explicit that you want an
>   object that implements `==` and `hashCode`.

## References

You can refer to [Style guide for Flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo), full list of [Dart's Linter Supported Lint Rules](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/), and [Effective Dart's Style Guide](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style).

Note, [Style guide for Flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo) is used among flutter community and takes precedence over LinterRules and Effective Dart's Style Guide especially within repo contributions. From what I've seen, [Style guide for Flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo) is more of a superset Style Guide that should honor Dart Linter rules.

Comment: so `int a = 10` or `var a = 10`?

Comment: Depends on the context. If it's a local variable or not.

i.e. within a class it's recommended to be explicitly typed. But within a function as a local variable it's recommended to be implicitly typed.

Comment: That's correct, it's a guide and sometimes people don't adhere to it. Though don't mistake developers using `final double foo =` in class declaration. As I said, it's recommended to specify type annotation **when the variable is not local**.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/transitions.dart#L354 I'm about it :) any claim on your answer

Comment: Yeah got what you mean. As I said it's a guide and sometimes people don't adhere to it. Personally in local scopes like within methods, I wouldn't want to write `Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions = Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus>();` But rather opt-in for `var permissions = Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus>();`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any difference between the two statements you gave.

And I don't see any downside to only declare the keyword "var", unless that your code might become a bit more difficult to read. On the other side, specifying the type might become a bit redundant sometimes.

But this is really just a question of taste

I advise you to pick between those two, and be consistent in your code.

If you choose to always specify the type, you can use `always_specify_types` in your file `analysis_options.yaml` :
https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/always_specify_types.html