# Why "var" instead of data type is considered a better practice in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was studying Dart and it is mentioned in the tutorial that when you are initializing the variable, use the keyword "var" instead of the type of data like "int". Dart will automatically infer that it is an "int" or "String" based on the initial value. But will it not be faster if we tell the dart directly that it is going to an "int". Dart is strongly typed and we cannot use the same variable for an integer and string like "javascript", then what is the purpose of "var" in dart context. It seems to me that using data type will be faster and easier. Why it is considered a better practice to use the "var"?

Comment: It will not affect runtime performance.  Type inference happens statically (i.e. at compile-time); the compiled code should be the same.  It could have some effect on compilation time, but it likely is negligible.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/64260613/, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61183907/, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/66836046/.

Answer (score 8):

A variable of type `dynamic` would be similar to javascript where it can change type during runtime. For example store an integer then change to a string.

`var` is not the same as dynamic. `var` is an easy way to initialise variables as you don't have to explicitly state the type. Dart just infers the type to make it easier for you. If you write `int number = 5` it would be the same as `var number = 5` as dart would infer that this variable is an integer.

The reason the tutorial might have said that `var` is better than `int` may be convention to make the code more readable but I believe it doesn't have any impact on your code. You can use either and it won't make a difference.

Comment: Also, using `var` makes it less likely that you remove the generic part of the type. A lot of time, we see code on SO where the programmer has written `List myList = someMethod()` where `someMethod` are really returning `List<String>`. But since they have explicit written `List`, this will make `myList` into `List<dynamic>`. If you instead had just used `var` or `final` as the type, you would have automatically got `List<String>`.

Comment: @twiz This is really a question about experience. But I will say that if you structure you code nicely and give your variables some good descriptive names, it will very rarely make the code more readable if method variables are defined with specific type. Remember, that we can be dependent on an IDE to make our life easier. So if I need to know a type, I will often just go to the variable and click Ctrl+Q in IntelliJ to get type information. And I can do this without scrolling to where the variable are defined. Code does not need to be 100% easy to read in notepad.

Comment: I agree with @twiz on this one. A properly named variable, say "listOfWords" for example, is not specific enough. It doesn't say what type of object these words are. They are probably strings, but could just as well be of a class called Word which contains a text along with other information, perhaps language. It's better to specify the type instead of "var". I'm using VSCode IDE and it won't show the type like IntelliJ does. It's a lot easier to navigate the code base if the type is stated before the variable. It also does make the code more readable.

Comment: I see, but `var number = 5` is less readable than `int number = 5`.

Answer (score 1):

the reason I think var is better is that it is slightly more convenience, for example

```dart
var n = 1;
int m = 1;
```

both `n` and `m` are integer

if some day you changed your mind and want to reinitialize them with new decimal number instead

```dart
var n = 9.9;
double m = 9.9;
```

in this case, var requires less typing and still able to infer the type correctly