# What's the rationale for not using explicit types?

Tags: dart, types, var

> Most local variables shouldn’t have type annotations and should be
> declared using just var or final. There are two rules in wide use for
> when to use one or the other:
>
> - Use final for local variables that are not reassigned and var for    those that are.
> - Use var for all local variables, even ones that aren’t reassigned.       Never use final for locals. (Using final for fields and top-level
>   variables is still encouraged, of course.)
>
> Either rule is acceptable, but pick one and apply it consistently
> throughout your code. **That way when a reader sees var, they know
> whether it means that the variable is assigned later in the function.**

From this, I'm inferring that we only use explicit types(like `int`) when they are fields(correct me if I'm wrong).

I don't quite understand the rationale of choosing `var` over explicit types. Using explicit types will well... explicitly tell me what type I'm using in comparison to `var`. That sounds like I should use explicit types rather than `var`.

The rationale(in bold) they provided for why `var` should be used can be applied to explicitly types as well, can't they?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/64260613, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61183907, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/66836046. (Also, this same question was asked yesterday in https://stackoverflow.com/q/67353497/.)

Comment: Oh my, the 1st and the 3rd links never popped up in my search. Guess, this should be closed as a dup then. Apologies. Thanks @jamesdlin for pointing that out.